# CSS Grid set number of columns for the top row only

Tags: css, css-grid

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 100px repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

i want the first row to be only 2 columns which will be my navbar, logo and nav links but can't seem to find out how maybe cause im searching the wrong thing.

Comment: use `grid-column : span 6;` for your 2 top element  see :  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row . **Also, you can add your html and css to demonstrate your issue** . It works the other way : create a grid, **then** dispatch your element inside the grid. element can be spanning a few cells through rows & columns. here an exemple of col spanning : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wrpRXG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) on your child elements

On your grid child elements (your navbar, for example), you can use the `grid-column` property. You can set start and end values for where you want the child to be positioned.

For example:

```
.navbar {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
}
```

### Next level: use [grid-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/grid_areas) to label your child elements

You might also want to consider looking into `grid-areas`, which is a nice way of labelling and referencing areas such as your header and navbar.

### References:

- [MDN: grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)
- [MDN: grid areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/grid_areas)